# How do I set up Intellij / jar manifests for bytecode instrumentation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, gradle, bytecode

Started looking into Java Bytecode Instrumentation.

And like so often, Hello World is what I start with.

**Short Version**: I built a project that prints `Hello World`, I now want to instrument that class such that it prints `Hello ASM`, instead. To that end, I have implemented a dummy agent that I later intend to modify such that it does the necessary changes. How do I modfiy the `build.gradle` files such that I can use/test it?

[EDIT : `git clone https://bitbucket.org/RKor/helloasm.git` ]

**Long version**:

```
package helloasm;

import helloasm.instrumentation_targets.HelloWorld;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().doSomething();
    }
}
```

where

```
package helloasm.instrumentation_targets;

public class HelloWorld {
    public String doSomething(){
        String output = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(output);
        return output;
    }
}
```

I make it return the output string so we can actually compare it in JUnit with a simple testcase

```
package helloasm.instrumentation_targets;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class HelloWorldTest {
    @Test
    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("Hello ASM",new HelloWorld().doSomething());
    }

}
```

Now obviously, the test will fail and the program will stubbornly print `Hello World`. Let's change that.

Java bytecode instrumentation requires providing an agent in `.jar` format.
As I'm using Intellij, I create a new module, "HelloWorldAgent", and into **its** `build.gradle` file, I add

```
implementation "org.ow2.asm:asm:5.2"
```

as a dependency.

Now we add an agent

```
package helloasm.agents

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {
    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation){
        HelloWorldInterceptor transformer = new HelloWorldInterceptor();
        instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer);
    }
}
```

and transformer

```
package helloasm.agents

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class HelloWorldInterceptor implements ClassFileTransformer{
    @Override
    public byte[] transform(
            ClassLoader loader,
            String className,
            Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
            byte[] classfileBuffer
    ) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        System.out.println(className + " loaded");
        return classfileBuffer;
    }
}
```

Doesn't do anything exciting yet, but I should like to first get it all to run before I continue.

We add to the submodule's `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    archiveName = "${rootProject.name}-${rootProject.version}-agent.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Premain-Class': 'ch.ethz.koradir.helloasm.agents.Agent',
                'Can-Redefine-Classes': 'true',
                'Can-Retransform-Classes': 'true',
                'Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix': 'true',
                'Implementation-Title': "HelloWorldInterceptor",
                'Implementation-Version': rootProject.version
        )
    }
}
```

Now what? back in the root project's `build.gradle`, I need to somehow specify that

- it should compile submodule `HelloWorldAgent` to a jar, first
- it should run (or have an option to run) with the `-javaagents` flag, providing that jar
- it should execute (or have an option to execute) the tests with the instrumented code

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- delete the `settings.gradle` file from `HelloWorldAgent`
- make your build a multi-project build by adding `include 'HelloWorldAgent'` to your root `settings.gradle` file
- change the three `rootProject` in `HelloWorldAgent/build.gradle` to `project`
- Add the following to your root `build.gradle`

---

```
evaluationDependsOn 'HelloWorldAgent'

test {
    def jarTask = project('HelloWorldAgent').tasks.jar
    dependsOn jarTask
    afterEvaluate {
        jvmArgs "-javaagent:$jarTask.archivePath"
    }
}
```

Your test will still fail, but you will see the output of your transformer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the record: This requires the tests be run with gradle -- which also means we need to recompile the project with gradle, too -- I can somewhat get around this, a bit, if I edit the run configurations to include ``-javaagent:.\HelloWorldAgent\build\libs\HelloWorldAgent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-agent.jar``, that way, I wouldn't need to recompile the entire project, but I'd still be relying on gradle to compile and rebuild the agent jar on changes and I'd have to manually edit the hardcoded path should it ever change.

Comment: Of course it does, that was what you asked about. Recompiling with Gradle is not the worst choice. Gradle always tries to do as less work as possible and is pretty good at that. If you enable incremental compilation for the JavaCompile tasks, this even works down to file level. There are many ways to improve your workflow. You could make IJ call Gradle instead of compiling itself, you can use the IDEA Gradle plugin to generate the IJ project files and configure it so that a runconfiguration with the correct agent config is created, ...

Comment: ... you can use dynamic agent registration at runtime instead of using --javaagent option if that is not too late for your use-case, you can make the run configuration that uses the agent jar call the Gradle task that produces it always before it runs, ..... There are many ways for improvement.

Comment: it wasn't a critique, just a comment for whoever - if any - may read this at a later date (this might actually include myself) since it's related to Intellij. I remain very grateful.

Comment: No worries, I didn't interpret it as criticism, I just wanted to give you pointers on how to make your life easier. :-)